# Does Android Studio only accept phones that are 11+?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to launch a test ad on Android Studio so that I can put interstitial ads on my app, but when I try launching the application on my connected device it opens for a split second before crashing. I understand that to connect you device via wifi your phone must be Android 11+, mine is the 9th version but I'm connecting it through a USB cable and it doesn't seem to mention any requirements for this method of connection. Wondering whether my Samsung phones version of Android is the root of the problem or whether it's just an error in my the code.

Comment: At least provide adb logs -- right now there's _nothing_ in this question to go off of to try to determine root cause.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actively using Android Studio with my Android 10 phone and I can confirm it works flawlessly, so probably your issue has something to do with your setup.
Are you using the provided ADB in Android Studio or have you installed it separately?
Did you enable USB debugging on your phone?
Does "adb connect" work when you exec it directly from the command line?

Comment: Yes I'm using the provided ADB in Android Studio, yes I've enabled USB debugging on my phone and yes "adb connect" works when executed from the command line

Comment: @Horatio then the app has bugs